# How to create and fire a Gdk.EventKey

Tags: c#, mono, keyevent, gtk#

I have a `Gtk.Window` which overrides `OnKeyPressEvent`

```
protected override bool OnKeyPressEvent(Gdk.EventKey evt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Captured key " + evt.Key);
    return base.OnKeyPressEvent(evt);
}
```

So I'm able to catch "real" keyboard actions.

Now I'd like to create something like a virtual keyboard (constists of simple buttons). But I didn't find any information about firing own key events.

Can someone tell me how I can trigger a key press programmatically with GTK# so that the action is handled in my `OnKeyPressEvent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for that.

If you know an other solution (maybe without native code), please tell me :)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct EventKeyStruct
{
    public EventType type;
    public IntPtr window;
    public sbyte send_event;

    public uint time;
    public uint state;
    public uint keyval;
    public uint length;
    public string str;
    public ushort hardware_keycode;
    public byte group;
    public uint is_modifier;
}


public static void SendKeyEvent(Gtk.Widget widget, Gdk.Key key)
{
    uint keyval = (uint)key;
    Gdk.Window window = widget.GdkWindow;
    Gdk.KeymapKey[] keymap = Gdk.Keymap.Default.GetEntriesForKeyval(keyval);

    EventKeyStruct native = new EventKeyStruct();
    native.type = Gdk.EventType.KeyPress;
    native.window = window.Handle;
    native.send_event = 1;
    native.state = (uint)Gdk.EventMask.KeyPressMask;
    native.keyval = keyval;
    native.length = 0;
    native.str = null;
    native.hardware_keycode = (ushort)keymap[0].Keycode;
    native.group = (byte)keymap[0].Group;

    IntPtr ptr = GLib.Marshaller.StructureToPtrAlloc(native);
    try
    {
        EventKey evnt = new EventKey(ptr);
        EventHelper.Put(evnt);
    }
    finally
    {
        //GLib.Marshaller.Free(ptr); //comment because otherwise it crashes here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is the memory automatically released somehow? I have tried freeing it with delay or calling the `Free` method of `EventHelper` but all caused app crash. It is not much memory (just some tens of bytes), so even if it is called a million times, it would only consume a few tens of megabytes. I am leaving as it is, but if you have found a way to release the memory, let me know.